# Remotely connect to MySQL on Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine, mariadb

My problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771981/google-compute-engine-lamp-stack-sftp-sql-and-https/33772878#33772878) but since I don't have enough reputation to write a comment AND the answer to that question dindn’t help, I am starting a new question.

I have an GCE VM instance with LEMP with MySQL Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.18-MariaDB and I'm trying to connect remotely to it from my local machine.

I already tried all the suggestions in the question link that I mentioned before.

This is my firewall configuration:

[image]

In my.cnf file I have:

> bind-address = 0.0.0.0

And about MySQL users privileges I have the following:

[image]
[image]

When I try to connect remotely with *wkreport* user I get the following result:

[image]

My question is, what am I missing ?!

Comment: do you have any firewall/iptables on the SQL machine? try looking at /var/log/messages as root while trying to login to mysql. you may find hints.

Comment: @Slava

In my.cnf file i have the following setup:
<pre>
    general_log_file     = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
    general_log            = 1
    log_warnings         = 2
<code>
And when tailing the log while trying to connect remotely i get no logs

Comment: @Slava  In the iptables INPUT rules im accepting tcp connections on 3306 like this:  
**ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql**

Comment: try tailing /var/log/messages after (or during) an attempt to login to mysql. maybe something else is blocking you, you might see it there.

Comment: @Slave I don't seem to have that /var/log/messages on my machine !? I'm looking to /var/log/mysql/mysq.log and i can see connection logs from localhost (connected via ssh on GCE VM) but when i try from my local machine to the GCE VM external IP no logs are written. Can't understand this behavior since i have configured firewall to accept tcp on 3306

Comment: @Slava Sorry, misspelled your name in the last comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution to my problem,

Special thanks to @Slava for pointing me the way, after all it was iptables.

So, I kept receiving a "MySQL connection refused" message when trying to connect remotely so I searched for a way to see TCP connection logs and I found the `tcpdump` command.

By running `sudo tcpdump port 3306 -vvv -n` I saw the following output every time I tried to connect remotely:

[image]

I searched the tcpdump man page and saw that R means for TCP RST (RESET) flag.

Searched a little bit and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272026/tcp-server-sends-rst-ack-immediately-after-receiving-syn-from-client) and its accepted answer led me again into IPTABLES that @Slava suggested since the first comment.

That's when I looked closely and saw that my INPUT ACCEPT tcp:3306 was defined after the REJECT TCP reject-with tcp-reset rule hence the log was showing.

[image]

After this I just removed the rule to accept tcp:3306 and prepended it to the reject tcp rules and voila!

```
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT {line number from the first reject tcp rule} -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

IPTABLES now looks like this and finally I can connect to MySQL remotely:
[image]

To list the iptables with line numbers type:

```
sudo iptables -nL --line-numbers
```

Final toughts:

- This can be improved by whitelisting the source IP address from where you're making the remote connection for security matters.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with a vm instance.
I tested everything and it was solved by creating a new user on mysql.

I used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server) to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for your input @Rafael Snor